# Android. VectorDrawable

Tags: android, vector-drawable

Загружаю в проект фон-картинку через VectorDrawable. На андроиде выше 5.0 все отлично, но ниже 5.0 фон получается размытый. Почему возникает такая проблема? И можно ли ее устранить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целях поддержки `Vector Drawable` и `Animated Vector Drawable` на устройствах с версиями `Android` до версии 5.0 (API-уровень 21),  доступны две новые библиотеки поддержки  [VectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.html) и [AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html): поддерживающие `vector-drawable` and `animated-vector-drawable`, соответственно.

Вставьте [следующий код](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) для настройки `vectorDrawables`

```
//For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

Comment: После вставки вашего кода вылетает данная ошибка: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: скиньте код где вы устанавливаете фон.

Comment: @zakiroof: интересная [диаграмма](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857755/5330439). Ознакомьтесь с ней.

Comment: а куда вы написали этот код?

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы изображение не было размытым увеличьте размер в xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="150dp" <- увеличьте эти значения
        android:height="50dp" <- увеличьте эти значения
        android:viewportWidth="41"
        android:viewportHeight="14">
```

Comment: Да, действительно, качество улучшилось, но при этом пропадает "резиновость" приложения. До этого, например, я указывал 24dp x 24dp и картинка сама растягивалась до нужного размера. А теперь если я укажу 30 х 30, то картинка станет длиннее на некоторых устройствах с маленьким разрешением, а на устройствах с большим разрешением будет нормально. Как это исправить?

Comment: Не понятно как квадратное изображение может растянуться только в одной плоскости.

Покажи разметку куда выводишь изображение и разметку самого изображения